# UITableViewCell detailTextLabel does not update its text when new value is assigned to it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uikit

I have been trying to use a Static Table View as a settings/options view for alarm functionality in my app. I been able to pass and update data back and forth various ViewControllers and update values.

Ever MPMediaPickerController will happily pass the data back and it will even update the delegate with the correct value after I save the value but it will not update the detailTextLabel before I save the alarmObject. I can see in my logs that object is even saved with the correct values when the ViewController is dismissed. The only odd thing is that that the VC in question is a child VC of another VC but I do not think that is the issue.

If it helps, all VCs are also part of a UINavigationController with the exception being the MediaPicker.

I have tried to reload the data, executing the change on the main thread, delaying the main thread to let all changes execute, reloaded the specific row for where the mediaCell is, calling needsDisplay and needsLayout and layoutIfNeeded on the cell,  nothing works. Any suggestions are greatly welcome as I been banging my head against this for the past few days and getting frustrating.

```
#import "AddAlarmTableViewController.h"
#import "ToneTableViewController.h"

@interface AddAlarmTableViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *mediaCell;

@end

@implementation AddAlarmTableViewController


@synthesize previousLabel, previousSoundAsset, previousRepeatArray,alarmDelegate,mediaCell;

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:NO];
    if(previousSoundAsset != nil) {
        mediaCell.detailTextLabel.text = previousSoundAsset;
    } else {
        mediaCell.detailTextLabel.text = @" ";
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"mediaCell"]) {
        UIAlertController *selectTypeAlertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Select Media From" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];
        //Creating actions
        UIAlertAction *cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel handler:nil];
        UIAlertAction *selectFromMusicAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Music" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
            [self launchMediaPickerController];
        }];
        UIAlertAction *selectFromToneAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Tone" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
            [self launchTonePickerController];
        }];
        //adding them to uialertcontroller;
        [selectTypeAlertController addAction:cancelAction];
        [selectTypeAlertController addAction:selectFromMusicAction];
        [selectTypeAlertController addAction:selectFromToneAction];
        [self presentViewController:selectTypeAlertController animated:true completion:nil];

    }
}
- (void)launchTonePickerController {
    ToneTableViewController *toneVC = [[ToneTableViewController alloc] init];
    toneVC.alarmDelegate = alarmDelegate;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:toneVC animated:true];

}
- (void)launchMediaPickerController {
    NSLog(@"Launching MPMediaPickerController");
    MPMediaPickerController *mediaPicker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeMusic];
    mediaPicker.delegate = self;
    mediaPicker.allowsPickingMultipleItems = NO;

    [self presentViewController:mediaPicker animated:true completion:nil];
}

//MPMediaPickerDelegate methods
- (void)mediaPickerDidCancel:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^ {
        NSLog(@"MPMediaPickerController dismissed");
    }];
}
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *)mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *)mediaItemCollection {
    MPMediaItem *selectedTrack = [[mediaItemCollection items] objectAtIndex:0];
    alarmDelegate.soundAsset = selectedTrack.title;
    mediaCell.detailTextLabel.text = alarmDelegate.soundAsset;
    alarmDelegate.appTones = [[NSNumber alloc] initWithBool:NO];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:true completion:^ {
        NSLog(@"MPMediaPickerController dismissed with %@", alarmDelegate.soundAsset);
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^ {
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    }];
}
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"repeatSegue"]) {
        DayTableViewController *daysViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        daysViewController.alarmDelegate = alarmDelegate;
        if(previousRepeatArray != nil) {
            daysViewController.previousSelection = previousRepeatArray;
        }
    }
    else if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"labelSegue"]) {
        LabelViewController *labelViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        labelViewController.alarmDelegate = alarmDelegate;
        if(previousLabel != nil) {
            labelViewController.previousLabel = previousLabel;
        }
    }
}
@end
```

Comment: Are you sure the outlet isn't nil?

Comment: Yes it not nil, I just double checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, as suggested by Apple's documentation, if you are working with storyboards and static table views, it is recommended to simply attach an IBOutlet to the item in question and use the IBOutlet to directly setting properties on the said item, in this case, the detailTextLabel. I still do not why I could not directly change the detailTextLabel through the cell that is returned to me in the didSelectRow UITableViewDelegate but there you go.

I suspect I did not try to execute this previously when I tried in a GCD block on the main thread so there that as well. Be warned that there is a perceivable delay for the actual delay to occur so be mindful of that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the value of previousSoundAsset. It may be empty string(not nil).

```
if(previousSoundAsset != nil || ![previousSoundAsset isEquals:@""]) {
    mediaCell.detailTextLabel.text = previousSoundAsset;
} else {
    mediaCell.detailTextLabel.text = @" ";
}
```

Comment: It not though, as I stated above, I can clearly see that value is being saved. It will present the updated value when I save it and go back to edit it.

Comment: You can print log before above code:
NSLog(@"previousSoundAsset=%@", previousSoundAsset);

Comment: I am saying it is not nil or empty.